# How to use update() functionality in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Inside my store function i have to search a name of a particular person, thus:

```php
$person = DB::select("select p.* from persons p where concat_ws(', ' ,p.family_name,concat_ws(' ',concat_ws(' ',p.first_name,p.middle_name),p.third_name)) like ?", [$request['person_name']]);
```

If this person exist i have to update the person and this one works:

```
Person::where('id', $person[0]->id)->update(['status' => 'Active']);
```

but not this one:

```php
$person[0]->status = 'Active';
$pArray = json_decode(json_encode($person[0]), true);
$per = new Person($pArray);
$per->update();
```

Comment: You are missing where condition. So logically, eloquent won't understand update without where condition

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that last block of code?

Comment: At the end of code i will return a view. In my database, my table ```application``` has ```person_id``` which is associated with my table ```person```. That code above is taken from ```store``` function of my ```ApplicationController```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have already created a new model instance, you would need to call the `save()` method.

```php
$per = new Person($pArray);
$per->save();
```

Or, you can use `update()` to pass data into an existing model.  But first, you need to retrieve the model you want to update.

```php
$per = Person::find($pArray['id']);
$per->update($pArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use your search query instead of mine. I think this will help you.

 $result = User::where('id', $userId)->first();
 $result->name = 'xyz';
 $result->update();
```

Comment: that won't work, `update()` expects an array, you mostly ment to use `save()` there

Answer (score 0):

For update data in laravel using model you need to pass where condition in it.

Sample example

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);
$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';
$flight->save();
```

Hope this helps you!